# MySQL - High Connections

Tags: mysql, connection

I run this command:

```
mysql> show status like '%onn%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| Aborted_connects         | 0     | 
| Connections              | 37226 | 
| Max_used_connections     | 45    | 
| Ssl_client_connects      | 0     | 
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0     | 
| Ssl_finished_connects    | 0     | 
| Threads_connected        | 4     | 
+--------------------------+-------+
```

I know I don't have a high traffic site, so the **Connections** number is confusing me.
I'm positive I close all my connections when I use PHP.

Are there other reasons why Connections keep growing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections):

> Connections
>
> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL
>   server.

It is not the number of simultaneous connections, but a cumulative number.

Answer (score 1):

You can Run Below command to know Traffic on your server.

```
Show global status  like '%Thread%';
```